# Testing for broken links in a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an existing rails application, where i want to test for broken links. which testing should i use integration testing or Rspec? Am new to BDD.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you write proper integration tests (e.g. with Cucumber or whatever) you should touch your entire front-end interface. E.g. click links, fill out forms etc.

This set of tests would give you an immediate warning when you have dead links in your app.

Comment: This begs the question: Who tests the tests?  Or perhaps "Quis custodiet ipsos custodes?"  If we had some way to automatically know when a link or a button was not clicked in the tests, then it would be enough to just make all of our tests complete.  But that would be just as generic as a test to test all the links, and would not be as efficient.  I just don't understand the widespread aversion to generic tests.

Answer (score 5):

I think it depends on why you are wanting to "test" for broken links.

**Scenario 1)** Ensuring URLs entered by users are correct might use a method like this:

```
def active_link?(url)
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  response = nil
  Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) { |http|
    response = http.head(uri.path.size > 0 ? uri.path : "/")
  }  
  return response.code == "200"
end
```

You can then use that in your Rspec tests:

```
active_link?('http://example.com').should be
```

**Scenario 2)** You just want to make sure all the links on your site work:

If this is the case, you might try using the Unix 'wget' command:

```
wget --spider -r -l 1 --header='User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0' http://example.com 2>&1 | grep -B 2 '404'
```

With Scenario 2, it will dump out all 404s to your terminal screen. It's a relatively simple matter to put that into a rake command; Jason Seifer has a great blog post on that (http://jasonseifer.com/2010/04/06/rake-tutorial)

Comment: Here you need to put the Net::HTTP.start in a "begin-rescue" block and also require 'net/http'. so it would be like this (replce ';' with newline):

    def active_link?(url);
      uri = URI.parse(url);
      puts uri.path;
      response = nil;
      require 'net/http';
      begin;
        Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) { |http|;
          response = http.head(uri.path.size > 0 ? uri.path : "/");
        };
      rescue;
        return false;
      end;
      return response.code == "200";
    end;

Comment: Pretty hard to do in a rails test environment, especially with logins and mocks.